# different class (css) for sidebar widgets

Tags: widgets, sidebar, css

I want to add different class (css) in widgets in site sidebar .

For example:

First widget in Sidebar -> class=sidebar-top1

Second widget in Sidebar -> class=sidebar-top2

third widget in Sidebar -> class=sidebar-top3

```
i want to add class in <div> tag.
```

how i can to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this post I wrote on the wordpress.org board... it has some functioning code you can work from: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-first-and-last-css-classes-for-sidebar-widgets

Comment: Nice! Wish I seen those topics yesterday. :) Anyway I needed to implement grid rows so different classes logic. One note for that code - no need to check for empty sidebar, hook fires per-widget so it simply cannot run when processing empty sidebar.

Comment: @Rarst Good call! I added a follow-up note with your comment on the original post--the WP board doesn't let you edit stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What a coincidence, I just spent several hours messing with widget classes. I won't post my resulting code because it does stuff that is more complex and out of context for your question. Here are basics (or maybe "basics"):

1. Widget is passed through `dynamic_sidebar_params` hook.
2. Widget data is `$params[0]`.
3. Sidebar name is `$params[0]['name']`.
4. Opening widget wrapper is `$params[0]['before_widget']`.

So you can filter this hook, check for sidebar you want to modify, keep track of widget count (likely with `static` variable), modify wrapper and return modified widget parameters.

I am way to sleepy to write out specific code, leave a comment if you still need help with this and I will get back to it tomorrow.

Comment: thanks Rarst 
but i dont understand your Description
beacuse i cant use of it
but math smath give a url that help me..
Have a good sleep :D